# Foundation JavaScript only fires on first event

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have foundation installed with the setup provided by foundation sites for sage (gulp bower). However, when my page loads the JavaScript only fires on the first event. So my carousel will only advance to the second image, and my search bar will appear, but I can’t get it to close. I don’t have any errors in my console, so I’m really stumped with this.

I know foundation is working as the carousel displays correctly and my mobile menu is hidden.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing a CSS package called motion-ui.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html

> Motion UI is a standalone library that powers the transition effects used in a number of Foundation components, including Toggler, Reveal, and Orbit. The transitions are powered by special transition classes that the Motion UI Sass creates. For example, here are two instances of Toggler—one using fade classes (.fade-in and .fade-out), and one using slide classes (.slide-in-down and .slide-out-up).